# how to calculate number of days that lies between four sets of dates

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have four dates

```
leavestartdate = '2021-05-25 00:00:00.000'
leaveenddate = '2021-06-05 00:00:00.000'

Reportstart = '2021-06-01 00:00:00.000'
Reportend = '2021-06-30 00:00:00.000'
```

I want to calculate number of days which lie between `leavestartdate`, `leaveenddate`, `Reportstart` and `Reportend`.

Here the number of days should be 5. (2021-06-01 to 2021-06-5)
`Reportstart` and `Reportend` can be different.

Is it possible with SQL?
Please suggest me something.

Comment: how is leavestartdate and leaveenddate relevant to days between Reportstart and Reportend?

Comment: you need to provide more sample data of various scenario and the corresponding result. Based on the one single sample data provided, it is simply `datediff()` between `Reportstart` and `leaveenddate `

Comment: reportstart date can be 2021-05-01 . Then it changes the scenario . 
if i have leavestart as 2021-05-25 and leaveend= 2021-06-05
and reportstart as 2021-05-01 and reportend as 2021-05-31
then answer should be 6 
because 6 days of leavestart and leaveend lies between reportstart and reportend .

Comment: Please [edit] any clarifications directly into your question.

Comment: If your "report" dates are parameters to a query and you want to find rows relevant to that period, do you want to include rows that are only completely "contained" within the report date period? Or do you want rows that "overlap" any part of the period? One sample row alone is not sufficient for you or anyone else to understand your goal.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you just need some `CASE` expressions

```sql
SELECT DATEDIFF(day,
    CASE WHEN @leavestartdate > @Reportstart THEN @leavestartdate ELSE @Reportstart END,
    CASE WHEN @leaveenddate < @Reportend THEN @leaveenddate ELSE @Reportend END
  ) + 1;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=84883032b826068b8ec022eb558952e5)